# Obtaining a list of non-linked models, in many_to_many relations, using Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have a User-Roles model, using Laravel 4 where a user can have many roles, using Eloquent. I can access all roles linked to a user easily using this code :

```
class User extends Model {
    protected $table = 'user';
    protected $fillable = array('name');

    public function rolesLinked() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\UserRoleLink', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

I've been trying to obtain the roles that are not linked to a user, to display on the specific user's page in a select box. Using this function, included in the User class.

```
public function rolesNotLinked() {
    $user = this
    $roles = Roles::whereDoesntHave('App\UserRoleLink',function($query) use ($user){
        $query->where('user_id',$user->id);
    });
}
```

The problem is, calling this function gives me the following error.

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::App\UserRoleLink()
```

I've tried using has with < 1 to see if the function was problematic, but [after reading this](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3413) and the online source code, the function call pretty much does what I've tried.

Is something wrong in my function call, or have I messed up configurations somewhere?

For reference, here are my other Model classes:

```
class UserRoleLink extends Model{
     protected $table = 'user_role_link';
     protected $fillable = array('role_id','user_id);

    public function role() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Role', 'role_id');
    }
}

class Role extends Model{
     protected $table = 'role';
     protected $fillable = array('name');
}
```

EDIT: I've found out that I messed up by fillables when I copy-pasted. It didn't fix the issue, but I guess that's one step closer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `whereDoesntHave` method, you must add the relation in your Role Model.

```
class Role extends Model{
     protected $table = 'role';
     protected $fillable = array('name');

     public function UserRoles() {
         return $this->hasMany('App\UserRoleLink', 'id');
     }
}
```

Also, the `whereDoesntHave` method first parameter is not thte model but the function of the relation:

```
public function rolesNotLinked() {
    $user = this
    $roles = Roles::whereDoesntHave('UserRoles',function($query) use ($user){
        $query->where('user_id',$user->id);
    });
}
```